# SQL JOIN AND GROUP BY

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I am pulling  data from 5 columns where there are two joins and I need to group by one of the columns.  However I'm getting an error when I try to group by at the end.  Do I need some sort of sub query?

```
SELECT 
    TERRITORY_T.TERRITORYID, 
    TERRITORY_T.TERRITORYNAME, 
    CUSTOMER_T.CUSTOMERID, 
    ORDER_T.ORDERID, 
    PRODUCT_T.PRODUCTID
FROM 
    TERRITORY_T, 
    CUSTOMER_T, 
    ORDER_T, 
    PRODUCT_T, 
    DOESBUSINESSIN_T
WHERE  
    TERRITORY_T.TERRITORYID = DOESBUSINESSIN_T.TERRITORYID
    AND CUSTOMER_T.CUSTOMERID = DOESBUSINESSIN_T.CUSTOMERID
GROUP BY 
    ORDERID
ORDER BY 
    TERRITORYID DESC, 
    CUSTOMERID
```

The Customer Table and the Orders Table both have CustomerID.  Do I need to query on them first, use group by, and then join with the other tables?

Comment: You query really makes no sense.  Start with a simple query and work from there.  Hint:  *Never* use comma in the `FROM` clause; *always* use explicit `JOIN`s.  Another Hint:  Figure out what you want to aggregate by and only select those columns, along with others that have *aggregation* functions.

Comment: `GROUPING BY` is an action of aggregation, meaning that all other fields being retrieved by the query must be **packed** together in some way (e.g. SUM, MAX, etc.). That is the reason for the error.